# Snakemake: temp files lead to immediate failure in repeated rule attempts

Tags: snakemake

I have a rule using the [bwa mem wrapper](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/bwa/mem.html) that sometimes fails due to cluster time limits. As this only happens occasionally, I do not want to generally increase the time limit for that job, but instead increase it with the number of attempts.

However, after failing due to cluster time limit, a lot of bwa mem tmp files are left in the output directory, which cause bwa mem to immediately fail in the next attempt. The generated tmp files are numbered `out.tmp.1.bam .. out.tmp.n.bam`, where `n` is some number as bwa mem sees fit, so I cannot simply mark these as temp files in Snakemake and rely on them being deleted on failure (I'm not even sure that this would happen - I don't know exactly when the deletion of files marked as temp is triggered...).

I considered the following solutions:

- Delete these files first (by not using the wrapper, but instead copy the wrapper code, and modify it to delete all `out.tmp.*.bam` files before running bwa mem), but this seems ugly.
- Use a shadow directory, in the hope that this is directory cleared after each attempt, but [the documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#shadow-rules) says

  > Shadow directories are stored one per rule execution in `.snakemake/shadow/`, and are cleared on successful execution.

  Hence, for a failed execution, the temp files would still be there, which will cause subsequent attempts to fail as well. I guess that this is done in order to be able to debug failed runs. But here, it hinders restarts.
- An alternative solution would be to have `onstart`, `onsuccess`, and `onerror` hooks per rule, as previously suggested in [#133](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/133), but that is an option for the future...

I have posted a [feature request](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/454) for this problem already, but maybe there already is a pure Snakemake solution already out there. Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: Are you sure bwa fails if the previous tmp files are present and not for other reasons? I don't see why that should happen... Does it have to do with the wrapper? In my opinion, your first solution is ok. Just make sure you don't delete tmp files that are currently used by other bwa processes (e.g. run each bwa job in a separate directory?)

Comment: Oh, I just re-ran, and the error is in fact due to samtools: `samtools sort: failed to create temporary file "mapped/S01a-1.sorted.tmp.0000.bam": File exists`. But, as this samtools call is part of the bwa mem wrapper, it doesn't change the general issue. 
As for the first solution: yes, it seems I have to do that. But having to copy a wrapper to solve that just does not seem like a nice solution at all.
And as for only deleting the correct files: They all have prefixes unique to their runs, so I'll use that to ensure correctness.

Comment: I might be able to cobble together a solution based on changing the tmp dir (https://github.com/samtools/samtools/issues/1035) via the `sort_extra` param of the wrapper, and cleaning that up with a special run that runs later. But again, that is just so ugly... :-( My wish-for solution is to simply add a per-rule `onstart` that cleans up all tmp files, or to use shadow directories that clean up on failure. But neither seems to be possible as of now.

Comment: The Best solution would be to start a PR for the wrapper and solve it for everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: From a bit more experimentation, it seems that `shadow: "full"` does the job, and indeed also deletes the files when the job failed. Not entirely sure though, and the documentation is not clear on that. But so far, it works.